# Prove by epsilon-delta that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x^3-4=-3$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I need to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x^3-4=-3$ with epsilon-delta.

**My work**

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 ,\exists \space \delta > 0: 0<|x-1|< \delta \implies |x^3-4+3| < \varepsilon$

Working with the consequent:

$|x^3-4+3| <  \varepsilon \iff |x^3-1| < \varepsilon \iff |x-1||x^2+x+1| < \varepsilon$

Multiplying the antecedent by $|x^2+x+1|:$

$|x-1|< \delta$ $/\cdot |x^2+x+1| \iff  |x-1||x^2+x+1|< \delta |x^2+x+1|$

Here i found a relation but i don't know how to proceed, and i don't know if this way is the best way to prove this. Any hints?

Comment: What can you say about $x^2+x+1$? Can you think of a bound for it?

Comment: @איתןלוי the minima is $3/4$

Comment: That's correct, but if we for example assume that $\delta<1$, can you say more than that? Do you understand why we can assume that $\delta<1$?

Comment: I know now if i assume that $\delta < 1$ i  can finish the proof,  but how can i get that $\delta < 1$ ?

Comment: You get to choose $\delta $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete the square:   $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34$.  Then if $\delta \lt1$, we get $\vert x^2+x+1\vert\lt (\frac52)^2+\frac34=7$.

So set $\delta =\operatorname {min}(\frac{\epsilon}7,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\delta < 1/2$, then $1/2<x<3/2$.

$$|x^2+x+1|=x^2+x+1 < 5$$

$$  |x-1||x^2+x+1|< \delta |x^2+x+1|<5\delta =\epsilon$$

You can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, we essentially want to show that $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ for every $|x-a|<\delta$; that is, we want to show that $|x^3-1|<\epsilon$ for every $|x-1|<\delta$. Let $\delta=1$. Then $|x-1|<\delta$ or simply $|x-1|<1\implies x\in(0,2)$; hence, we also see that $|x^2+x+1|<|2^2+2+1|=7$. This implies that we should choose $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{7}\}$. Why? Because, if so, then we have
$$
\begin{align*}
|(x^3-4)-(-3)|
&= |x^3-1|\\[0.5em]
&= |x-1||x^2+x+1|\\[0.5em]
&< \frac{\epsilon}{7}\cdot 7\\[0.5em]
&= \epsilon.
\end{align*}
$$
Hopefully that supplies the missing detail you needed.

Comment: I understand everything, the only problem that i have is, why $\delta = 1$, how can i derive that assumption, it's always recommendable to assume $\delta = 1$ in these proofs and then assume smaller numbers?

Comment: It's not a *requirement* to assume $\delta=1$ at first, but it is often helpful/conventional. You can just as well try $\delta=2$ at the beginning, in which case we can see where $|x-1|<2=\delta$, and we see that $|x-1|<2\implies x\in(-1,3)$, whereby we see that $|x^2+x+1|<13$ implies we should choose $\delta=\min\{2,\frac{\epsilon}{13}\}$. Does that make sense?